# Having trouble using jQuery to toggle a slide down nav element

Tags: jquery

I have a nav bar that when I over over an element the next list displays. But when my mouse leaves the original nav the list dissappears. I want the list to stay when it is overed upon. Can you please help?

http://jsfiddle.net/GxshD/

Comment: how long do you want it to stay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your event handler is attached to your `li.drop` element, you need to encapsulate your child menu in that element like so...

```
<li class="drop">
    <a href="#">Recruiter Tools</a>
    <div class="recToolbardrop" style="display:none;">
        <ul class="recToolbardrop">
            <li><a href="#">Featured Tools</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">All Tools</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the second function from your jQuery.  It should show this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.drop').mouseenter(function () {
        $('div.recToolbardrop').slideDown('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: "I want the list to stay when it is hovered upon" seems to imply he wants it to disappear again when he is not hovering over it.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/daybreaker/fgtrR/

Put `ul.recToolbardrop` inside `li.drop`, so that `li.drop` encapsulates it.

It hovers up because you are technically not hovering over`li.drop` anymore, because you are displaying an entirely new div beneath it.  If you put `ul.recToolbardrop` in the `li.drop`, you will not leave `li.drop` when you mouse over any of the new `li`s.

Also, for the record, there are several pure CSS examples of how to do this, unless youre specifically trying to support older browsers that dont recognize `:hover` on all CSS tags.

Answer (score 0):

add the mouseleave event to div.recToolbardrop and not to li.drop